# pyqt4 + pyyaml/ruamel.yaml dump + pyinstaller bundling breaks application

Tags: pyqt4, pyinstaller, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm confused with some specific behaviour and can't find some informations that help me understand the error.

The situation is as follows: I made a small `pyqt4` app that at some point dumps an `OrderedDict` to a yaml string using `pyyaml` or `ruamel.yaml` (tried both) and writes this to a file, or reads from this file. This goes very well executing the code as normal. Now I want to distribute my app by bundling it into a single file windows exe using `pyinstaller`.

Now if I directly use `yaml.dump()` or `ruamel.yaml.dump()` in a method of my `pyqt4` form class to generate the yaml-string and write to a file (the standard way using `with open ...`), I am able to bundle the app using `pyinstaller` and the exe runs fine.

However, if I write a small function in a sub-folder/module that uses the exact same call to pyyaml (`yaml.dump(dict)`) or ruamel.yaml (`ruamel.yaml.dump(dict, Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper)`) to generate the yaml string and save to a file using `with open ...` and use this in my `pyqt4` method (I just wanted to make things more readable), `pyinstaller` starts to load a bunch of modules and does a lot more stuff (according to console output), resulting in the exe file beeing almost 5 times larger plus unusable throwing a fatal error `pyi_rth_pkgres returned -1` at start.

Unfortunately, I don't understand much from either console output or warnings log, viewable [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/tku137/fe4e872e2d6b6a56c323). Maybe I am searching for the wrong terms. I also tried renaming the module to prevent shadowing.

Now my question is, does anybody know whats going on and can explain this behaviour?

Comment: `ruamel.yaml` is a namespace package, and it could well be that pyinstaller doesn't properly handle that. Because of the way its setup.py is handling things you cannot e.g. do `python setup.py install` but `pip install .`. However PyYAML never had this setup, so it is strange both show the problem. What is the name of the submodule that you are using, have you tried another name?  I have seen e.g. `pip` screw things up because it does `import parser` when there is `parser.py` in your program.

Comment: That it breaks is not so strange as `futures`  in Python 2 only, the question is why this gets pulled in. I certainly don't use any of that in `ruamel.yaml`

Comment: I put the function to write the yaml string to a file in my own module inside my package and named it `io`. I refactored it into `guffel_bla` to make shure `io` was not shadowed from some outer scope or something. However, the strange thing is, that if I put the code as a method in the pyqt4 form class everything works, if I put it in another (selfmade) module, it doesn't. That is basically the thing that drives me nuts :/

Comment: With `io` being the standard lib strange things are to be expected, but not this and certainly not after refactoring. Is the project somewhere, I have never used pyinstaller and don't want spent too much time on trying to reproduce this. BTW my interest, in case you hadn't realised yet is that I am the author of ruamel.yaml

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't realise @Anthon, my bad. I did some more tests and it seems to be not related to ruamel.yaml or pyyaml, but rather simply the standard lib `open` triggers the errors. Anyway, unfortunately I am not allowed to share publicly until now, as this is part of a research project. I'll contact you via email to find a way, maybe you are still interested although not related to ruamel.yaml. But for your interest, I'll definetely stick with ruamel.yaml in the form class method as I like it way better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of trial and error, I finally got it working.

I created a new module and build the dumping functions inside it. `pyinstaller` and the bundled exe work flawless. However, if i do the exact same thing in the previous module, even refactoring the name, it does not work. I even copied the complete code to the old module and it doesn't work. I have no idea why and at this point I am too afraid to ask :|

I am just glad it works now.